# How to replace existing value of ArrayList element in java with beanutils

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-commons-beanutils

I have class

```
class cust{
private String name;
private int id;

//Getter and setters
//equals
//hashcode
//toString
}
```

In my main class

```
List<Customer> custList =  new ArrayList<Customer>;
```

custList has unique customers added in it.

If I add new customer into list I need to replace the old customer with same and ID using beanutils.

This is my Beanutils code

```
  BeanUtils.setProperty("customer", "custList[0]", customer);
```

PS: I have overriden equals & hashcode method.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you got to use BeanUtils?

Why not just find the element in the list and overwrite it?

```
public void addOrReplace(List<Customer> customers, Customer customer) {
    int index = -1;

    for(int k = 0; index != -1 && k < customers.size(); k++) {
        if(customers.get(k).getId() == customer.getId()) {
            index = k;
        }
    }

    if(index == -1) {
        customers.add(customer);
    } else {
        customers.set(index, customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: my implementation only with beanutils. I have simplified the above example only for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the gist of BretC's answer, but my implementation is more concise and leaves the original list untouched:

```
public List<Customer> addOrReplace(List<Customer> customers, Customer customer) {
    return customers.stream()
             .map(c -> c.getId() == customer.getId() ? customer : c)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```